# path format is not supported in ssrs subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I have created an SSRS standard subscription for one report.After the subscription's scheduled time,i am getting a message like "Failure writing file \D:\testexcels\FirstReport.html : The given path's format is not supported." in report manager subscription page.The sql server job is sucess and
there was no error while entering path at the time of creation.I have tried with dfferent format like pdf,html etc but same error is comming.please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The backslash before the D is incorrect. It should be just `D:\testexcels\FirstReport.html`.

Comment: No,We have to specify the path by starting with //. Other wise it will throw error when we create the subscription.I have tried with \\localhost\D:\testexcels\FirstReport.html also.

Comment: If you are using a unc path the format is \\servername\sharedfolder\

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the path like this( UN\ServerName\ShareName\FileName)

Answer (score 0):

**how to give correct UNC path to ssrs reporting subscription**

goto window

press window key and R

type   \**DEVI**\C$

and enter      --**DEVI** is my local Machine name your PC name will be different

your destination path will be like this formatt.
**\Devi\c$\Users\Abhirup Subba\DestinationFolder**

from there goto specific path you want to save file and copy the whole path to subscription

**make sure your destination folder should give full access to file ..like sharing to everyone..**